# How to make previous day's date and today's date only accessible in date time picker in Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to check on a condition where the today's date is only accessible to get selected in the date time picker in Odoo and the code is as follows.

```
def onchange_date(self, cr, uid, ids, fdate, context=None):
if fdate:
if datetime.strptime(fdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date() <> 
datetime.now().date():
return { 'value': { 'fdate': False } }
return fdate
```

I also wanted to make the previous day i.e yesterday's date to be available to the user to get selected along with today's date.

Answer (score 1):

```
selected_date = datetime.strptime(fdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
yes_date = datetime.strptime(fdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").relativedelta(days = -1).date()
today = datetime.now().date()
if selected_date <> today and selected_date <> yes_date
```

And add the import file for relative delte

Comment: selected_date = datetime.strptime(fdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()                                                                     TypeError: must be string, not bool. I am getting this error Vigneshwaran

Answer (score 1):

If you only use Dates, you should use `date` instead of `datetime`, and if first if you only want a user use the date of today, get automatically the date of today and put it `readonly`, something like this:

```
...
import time
...
#here you got a field with the date of today.
date_today = fields.Date('Today is: ', default = lambda *a: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), readonly = True)
```

And if you want what one user only be able to choose the days yesterday and today, it's a little bit more laborious, I know this is not the best way to do it but it work fine.

```
...
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError
...

chosen_date = fields.Date('Chosen day: ', default = lambda *a: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

@api.onchange('chosen_date'):
def _onchange_chosen_date(self):
    yesterday = str( int(time.strftime("%d")) - 1 )
    if len(yesterday) == 1:
        yesterday = '0' + yesterday
    yesterday_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-" + yesterday)
    if self.chosen_date != time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") or self.chosen_date != yesterday_date:
        return { 'warning': {'title':"Warning", 'message':"You are only able to choose only yesterday and today...!"}}
```

**EDIT**

I only use V8, but I know something of V7 syntax!

1th.

```
...
import time
...
#here you got a field with the date of today.
date_today = fields.date('Today is: ', default = lambda *a: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), readonly = True)
```

2th.

```
...
from openerp.osv import osv
...

chosen_date = fields.date('Chosen day: ', default = lambda *a: time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

def _onchange_chosen_date(self, cr, uid, ids, chosen_date, context=None):
    yesterday = str( int(time.strftime("%d")) - 1 )
    if len(yesterday) == 1:
        yesterday = '0' + yesterday
    yesterday_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-" + yesterday)
    if self.chosen_date != time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") or self.chosen_date != yesterday_date:
        raise osv.except_osv(("Warning"),("You are only able to choose only yesterday and today...!"))
```

And in the XML:

```
<field name="chosen_date" on_change="_onchange_chosen_date(chosen_date)" />
```

I hope this can be helpful for you!!!

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'Date'
name 'api' is not defined . these are the few errors i get Juan Salcedo. any idea on this ?

Comment: I supposed you are using Odoo v8, in this case you need to add this line at the top of your .py file `from openerp import models, fields, api`, after that you can use `Date` and `@api`, your second error, `module object has no attribute 'many2one'` you are trying to define a 'many2one' field in V7 syntax for OpenERP, you need to use `Many2one` for V8 syntax, let me know your discharges!

Comment: Juan Salcedo, yes you are absolutely right, would you mind telling how will i be able to implement your code in for V7 ?

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot Juan Salcedo, Will try on it and let you know it.. :)

Comment: AttributeError: 'registers.visitors' object has no attribute '_ids'. Do you know what this error is related to Juan Salcedo ?

Comment: Even though I implemented the above changes of your code in my module, I am getting the error

Comment: sorry the definition of the onchange method in XML was wrong, take a look now! Let me know your discharges!

Comment: Juan Salcedo, I am getting the following error :                                       if len(self) == 1:
  File "/home/administrator/Odoo-1/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 5381, in __len__
    return len(self._ids)
AttributeError: 'registers.visitors' object has no attribute '_ids'

Comment: I never used `if len(self) == 1`, this line should be `if len(yesterday) == 1:` like in my code.

Comment: yes the code is same Juan Salcedo :). the error was like that though.